# Ajax json POST and Spring MVC Controller 8

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring

I have ajax json POST method like this.

```
$(function () {
                $('#formId').submit(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault(); // prevent this form from being submited
                    var userJson = $('#id').val();
                    alert(userJson);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/MobitelProgressTool/ajaxcall",
                        data: userJson,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            alert(data);//handle it in a proper way
                        },
                        failure: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(textStatus);//handle it in a proper way
                        }
                    });
                    alert("mm");
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

Controller to handle post request

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/ajaxcall"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody// <== this annotation will bind Arr class and convert to json response.
    public List<String> addAnotherAppointmenttt(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody String userJson, Model model, BindingResult errors) {
        System.out.println("*******88888" + userJson);
        //List<String> ll = stageViiChartDataServices.findByUpdated_Scope(userJson);
        List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You");
        return messages;
    }
```

but I cannot getting mesages list values,. I'm not sure how to correct above code.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your javascript I see that you post a value in this form  `var userJson = $('#id').val();`.

In this way you ask at jQuery to retrive a value. however you should post a json, and not a value.  A think like this may be fine:

```
var value = $('#id').val();
var json = {'id': value}
```

then a my personal advice was don't use if it is possible `HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response` in your controller, instead uses Spring abstraction, `@RequestBody String userJson, Model model, BindingResult errors` is fine!

I hope that this can help you